# Black screen with only cursor visible at bootup

Tags: boot, kde

Im running kde neon with plasma 5.12.3. I had several programs open.  I used sudo xkill to close one program in the panel(i think the program was discover).  As soon as i clicked the tab in the panel my screen went black with only mouse cursor showing.  I did a hard reboot but after getting the 'loading kde neon 5.12.3' screen,  i again end up at the black screen with only mouse cursor visible. No greeter or anything?  Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED !!! 
:) i solved the problem. the issue was that i had recently used back-in-time to make a backup of my system and this caused my home folder to become full. This apparently doesnt allow the gui to load in startup. i went to the tty2 and deleted the snapshot , deleted /tmp and then remade tmp. restarting cleared up the problem. i have been looking for a solution for past 24hrs. i thought it was something to do with sddm or Xserver. Its very frustrating but thank God i was able to stumble upon the solution.